# sbt failed to download launcher

Tags: linux, scala, sbt

When I am trying to run 'sbt' on terminal, it is showing like this:

```
downloading sbt launcher 1.5.5
cat: /home/knoldus/.cache/sbt/boot/sbt-launch/1.5.5/sbt-launch-1.5.5.jar.sha1: No such file or directory
shasum: standard input: no properly formatted SHA checksum lines found
failed to download launcher jar: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.5.5/sbt-launch-1.5.5.jar (shasum mismatch)
```

Comment: Looks like a network/proxy issue on your end.

Answer (score 3):

i had the same error and i just move to the directory and download the file missing manualy

```
 cd  ~/.cache/sbt/boot/sbt-launch/1.5.5/
 wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-sbt/sbt-launch/1.5.5/sbt-launch-1.5.5.jar
```

then i run

```
 sbt package
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install curl. It is used in the sbt launcher shell script to download the file sbt-launch-1.5.5.jar.sha1 mentioned in the error message. If curl is missing, that will result in the error you've observed.

Answer (score 0):

SBT package downloaded from the official website includes `sbt-launch.jar` in `<sbt-install-folder>/bin` directory. SBT launcher `sbt` is a shell script that searches for this JAR. If the JAR is not found, it will try to download it from the internet and fail if the machine is behind a proxy.
So, when this happens, first thing is to check the `sbt` file location and if `sbt-launch.jar` is present. If the JAR is missing, it can be copied from the official SBT distribution, even if the machine is behind the proxy or offline.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is apparently with command `curl --output` not being able to open the output file. In my `/usr/bin/sbt` there is a function

```
download_url () {
  local url="$1"
  local jar="$2"
  mkdir -p $(dirname "$jar") && {
    if command -v curl > /dev/null; then
      curl -L "$url" --output "$jar"
    elif command -v wget > /dev/null; then
      wget -O "$jar" "$url"
  fi
} && [[ -f "$jar" ]]
```

Changing the `curl` line to:

```
curl -L "$url" > "$jar"
```

Fixed the issue for me. I have no idea what the underlying problem with `curl` is, but it happened both when installed with `apt` and `snap`.